# How can I create a binary pan gesture recognizer for x or y axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I would like to create a pan gesture recognizer and attach it to a view.

The gesture should only take into consideration movement on one of the axises X or Y.

What I have so far is pretty crude

```
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = recognizer.state;
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"state = %d : panned to %@",state,NSStringFromCGPoint(translation));


    if ((recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded))
    {
        CGFloat translationX = translation.x;
        if (ABS(translation.y) > 20 && ABS(translation.y) > ABS(translation.x))
        {
            // this is not a valid x pan because the vector has to much "y" movement in it
        }
        // need to do similar for x axis
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind embedding your view in a ScrollView then you can just set `directionalLockEnabled` to `YES` and that will take care of it.  You can also take out the scroll indicators to make it look the same as it would with a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: I can't do that because it would destroy other gestures in superviews